# webbrowser class cookies doesn't work

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, authentication, webbrowser-control

I'm developing an Asp.net MVC application, and in it I use webbrowser class to login to a website.
this works fine in local computer but when I publish my project in server, after navigating to website and trying to login to web site the webbrowser class navigates to cookie required page. I have a dedicated windows server 2012 R2, what should I do?

Comment: What do you mean by WebBrowser control? the only WebBrowser control I know is for a WinForms application and not a MVC one. More info please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one day battling we solved the problem by changing AppPool identity to administrator.